# Could not create a trigger for a table on cassandra

Tags: triggers, cassandra

I tried the cassandra version of 2.2.6 (a docker image) and 3.7 (the latest version, not with docker). Both of them report the same issue when I creating trigger for a table.

[Exception when creating cassandra trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5xEB.png)

```

```
package com.ttData.triggers;

import ...

public class DataTrigger implements ITrigger {
private Properties properties = loadProperties();

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;

private static AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(1);

@Override
public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update) {
    ...
    return Collections.singletonList(audit.build());
}


private static Properties loadProperties()
{
    ...
    return properties;
}
```

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use single-quote instead instead of double-quote for className

```html
cqlsh:test> CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger on mytable using "className"; 
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:42 mismatched input 'className' expecting STRING_LITERAL (...TRIGGER myTrigger on mytable using ["classNam]e";)">
cqlsh:test> 
cqlsh:test> CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger on mytable using 'className'; 
ConfigurationException: <ErrorMessage code=2300 [Query invalid because of configuration issue] message="Trigger class 'className' doesn't exist">
```

Comment: Thanks, but single-quote doesn't work either. It gets worse even, that it reports "Trigger class <classname> doesn't exist." Actually, it does exist. I putted the JAR file under the path_to_cassandra/conf/triggers/.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the cassandra source code, I think this is a bug.

Even though the trigger directory and trigger classes are both correct, it could still reports error that the trigger class doesn't exist.

The reason is that the working thread for creating trigger is not a secure thread which should be managed by cassandra's SecurityManager and belongs to a SecurityThreadGroup. So, an exception will be thrown when validating security failed.